# Convert dynamic SQL Server Pivot to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written below stored procedure in sql server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_getQuantityBilling()
--  VARIABLE --
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = group_concat(name)
from visit_groups where arm_id='377';

set @query = 'SELECT id, service, rate, subjectcount, armDetailsId, totalHours,' 
         + @cols + ' FROM 
         (
            select protocols.id, arms.name, visit_groups.name as visitGroup, services.name as serviceName,  visits.quantity, 
            line_items_visits.subject_count
            from protocols,arms,visit_groups,visits,line_items,line_items_visits,services
            where protocols.id = arms.protocol_id
            and visit_groups.arm_id = arms.id
            and visits.visit_group_id = visit_groups.id
            and line_items_visits.arm_id = arms.id
            and visits.line_items_visit_id = line_items_visits.id
            and line_items_visits.line_item_id = line_items.id
            and services.id = line_items.service_id
            and protocols.id = ''' + 591 + '''

        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(isActive)
            for visitName in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p';

execute (@query)
```

I am trying to convert this into mysql server but I am not sure how to declare the variables in mysql stored proc and how to run all these quesry together where result generated by previous query can be used in next query.

Also below query:

```
select @cols = group_concat(name) 
from visit_groups where arm_id='377';
```

is giving error

> Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT)
>   and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='  0.000 sec

so i looked for the solution and made it like this

```
select @cols = group_concat(name) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci from visit_groups 
where arm_id='377';
```

Now I am getting result as 0 with a column name `@cols = group_concat(name) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` , but the result should actually look like visit1, visit 2 because that is what I am getting in sql server.

**Edit**

```
  SELECT id, name, visitGroup, serviceName, quantity, subject_count,' 
         + [Visit 1],[Visit 2] + ' FROM 
         (
            select protocols.id, arms.name, visit_groups.name as visitGroup, services.name as serviceName, 
            visits.quantity, 
            line_items_visits.subject_count
            from protocols,arms,visit_groups,visits,line_items,line_items_visits,services
            where protocols.id = arms.protocol_id
            and visit_groups.arm_id = arms.id
            and visits.visit_group_id = visit_groups.id
            and line_items_visits.arm_id = arms.id
            and visits.line_items_visit_id = line_items_visits.id
            and line_items_visits.line_item_id = line_items.id
            and services.id = line_items.service_id
            and protocols.id = ''' + 591 + '''

        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(isActive)
            for visitName in (' + [Visit 1],[Visit 2] + ')
        ) p'
```

main issue is running this query, it shows error in mysql that pivot is used at wrong position but in sql it works fine. Anyway to turn this query into mysql pivot query.

Note: this Visit 1 and Visit 2 I am generating dynamically but just for this solution I copied here manually.

Comment: what does `select group_concat(name) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci from visit_groups 
where arm_id='377';` return when you run it outside the procedure?

Comment: I am getting result as 0 with a column name @cols = group_concat(name) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: but if I run without COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci then I get my desired result like visit 1, visit 2

Comment: it works for me:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iApYsz5qniSQ9cgJqgTjKM/0

Comment: I am getting it correctly, but when I use @col= then it does not show me result

Comment: main issue is with the second part of the question where I am using pivot

Comment: see my edited post

Comment: Did you try `select @cols := group_concat(name)` for mysql syntax?

Comment: yes it worked that way, see my edited post, now the issue is with the pivot part of my question